# need to install Windows Server over the current linux server

Tags: linux, installation, windows-server-2012-r2

My company has rented a dedicated server. Usually the company I have rented from in the past installs a non registered version of Windows. I update it and install our own license.

This time, it looks like x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu was installed, at least that is what is shows when I log in. I am able to log in through putty without issue though I have never mounted and installed a windows OS through Linux.

I am trying to get this up and running as quickly as possible without incurring extra fees. So, that means I'd like to avoid contacting them to reinstall a Windows OS. This is not a managed server.

How do I install Windows on a server that has Linux already installed on it without it being a dual boot machine? I'd like to wipe it and install Windows 2012.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is what is installed:

Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 x86_64

**EDIT #2**

This is the connection that I have available:

[image]

Comment: Do you have IPMI or something similar on the server? You're generally going to need physical access, or some kind of baseband management system to mimic physical access to do it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes I do. Any links or suggestions on how I install over IPMI? I've not used it much.

Comment: Neither have I. Its the sort of information you *should* have in your question so someone who has can help. Considering there's many different flavours of out of band managerment, what version you are using and what you have available is *essential* here.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I have added the remote management controller printscreen. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: I think so. Its probably idrac. What model's the server?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I assume you mean this:  Dual Xeon l5639 Hex Core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I found this out long after I had the server host install it for me, you have to install the operating system after you connect.

What I mean by that, is you will be given the option to connect via a java applet to the server's console. Once you do, you can then upload/mount an iso to the server from that point. It is an top on your bar at the top of your connection.

For me, it was these steps:

```
Connect to your IPMI
Click on Remote Control 
Click on Console Redirection 
Download the applet and run it. 
Once you have connected then at the top of that window, click on DEVICE -> REDIRECT ISO
```

[image]

Note: I noticed I had to click on MOUSE -> SYNC CURSOR to get the screen to respond.

Hope that helps the next person.